# Spring boot Load all files based on pattern and place it in HashMap

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, configuration

I am developing an app where there will be a properties file for each type of database.

- I want to load the properties file corresponding to the database based on the driver available in classpath using spring boot custom auto configuration and put it in a common holder object as a map.
- For example, lets say I have oracle driver on classpath, So i need to load oracle-metadata.properties and place it in map with key as "oracle" and value as the properties object.

Current Approach

```
@ConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource("classpath:oracle-metadata.properties")
public class OracleMetadataConfiguration{
```

//if i have the object attributes corresponding to properties file, i will end up having duplicate attributes for each type of database
    }

```
Application.properties

org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
com.**.autoconfiguration.OracleMetadataConfiguration
```

How do i use the different instance representation for same configuration object structure?
What is the best way to design this?

Comment: Why? What isn't possible with Spring Boot detection and default properties in `application.properties` using the regular mechanisms? For some reason feels like you want to work around the default mechanism instead of embracing it.

Comment: @Deinum Is there a way to load properties for all types of databases with single configuration class?I have oracle-metadata.properties, db2-metadata.properties,sql-metadata.properties,etc and I need to store it as map of objects with key as each database type

Comment: Why do you need that... To me it looks like a convoluted way of trying to store properties. Instead create an `application-<db>.properties` and use an `ApplicationContextInitializer` to determine which additional Spring Profile to create based on the available JDBC driver. (Still this looks quite convoluted to me because I hardly can imagine that each environment has the same jdbc settings).

Comment: Just to additional context, there may be multiple jdbc deivers active at the same time as it is a requirement as part of the app i am building.the properties file dorsnt store the connection settings ..its some query related metatdata for each type of database.

Comment: Where did I say you can only have 1 active profile? You can have multiple active profiles and all those property files will be loaded.

Comment: Do we have an example code of how to achieve this?

Comment: Why would you need a sample there is nothing to code as that is already support out-of-the-box by Spring Boot.

Comment: I guess the part i dont quite understand is when we add multiple active profiles using application context initializer,how does the values of each property file gets stored.the key names are same across property files.